# When an object’s destructor in C++ would be called?

Tags: c++

*(C++ related questions)*
Select each of the following instances in which an object’s destructor would be called.

1.Static variable goes out of scope (Correct Answer)

2.When delete is called on a pointer to an object (Correct Answer)

3.Dynamic variable goes out of scope

4.When the garbage collector is called

I know for 4, naive C++ has no gc. Can anyone explain why 1 is correct?

Comment: Why do you think 1) would be incorrect?

Comment: So your question is just _why a destructor of class is called when a static variable of that class goes out of scope?_ All the rest is unnecessary to the question and can be removed.

Comment: What you may be missing is  "When does a static variable go out of scope?" Answer that you should have your explanation.

Comment: Mind you whoever wrote this question might by mixing up the terms static and automatic. Very very different concepts in C++, and I hope to Crom that your instructor knows the difference. Hard to be sure, though. Either way the answer stays the same.

Comment: What is a "dynamic variable" and when does it go out of scope?

Comment: You are right in that C++ doesn't have a tracing garbage collector, but it does have reference counting garbage collectors. And those *will* call destructors (if defined)

Comment: Why do you think (1) is correct?

Comment: What is `naive C++`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When does an object's lifetime expire and its destructor is called?

Depends on the objects `Storage Duration` type:

- **Automatic**: When execution exits the scope the variable is declared in.
- **Dynamic**:   When `delete` is called on the pointer.
- **Static**: In reverse order of creation after `main()` exits.
- **thread**: In reverse order of creation after the thread exits.

Comment: Thank you for your help, really help me.